# (C#) Getting the index from a remove char of a TextBox WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox

I have a `TextBox` where the user can add and remove text, however each char relates to a row on a DataGridView, with a variety of user-selectable options. So knowing what char is being removed is very important because the DataGridView needs to know what row must be removed.

At first, I had a simple string-compare method, but with duplicate char sequences (e.i. "aaaa") it couldn't figure out which letter was removed and defaulted to returning the index of last char in the sequence. So I went online to see if there was a way to track the text caret's position, and there is...but not for WinForms. The only aspects I found for the Caret was `SelectionStart`, `SelectionLength` and `SelectionText`; which will be usefully for batch remove, but not when the user hits the backbutton/deletebutton.

I'm pretty stumped right now. The "easiest" solution is switching to XAML because it tracks the Caret Position... but that feels like quiter talk. Though with that said, I still have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: It sounds like an easier to use UI could bedevised.  Context menus and click events on the DGV come to mind

Comment: Did you think about trapping KeyPress events in the text box?

Comment: It is not enough to detect which character is missing or where the selection is, because it is possible to delete backwards (with Backspace) and forwards (with Delete). It is also possible to extend the selection and to delete several characters at once. Therefore, additionally to where the selection is and how long it is, you need to know which key is being pressed. As @NicholasHunter said, you must trap the key events.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes & @/NicholasHunter : Yea, I was thinking about ta system that not only trapped Backspace and Delete, but also the arrow keys so that the user could navigate through their textbox. What I worry about is trapping the shift+ and ctrl+ combinations and if the user uses their mouse to select a location...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to define the variable `originalText` to save origianl textbox text and `textlength` to save text length.

Subscribe to `textBox1_Enter` to give them the initial value.

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textlength = textBox1.Text.Length;
    originalText = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Then subscribe to `textBox1_TextChanged` to get the `deleted chars`.

```
int textlength;
string originalText;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textlength > textBox1.Text.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You deleted the char from {textBox1.SelectionStart} to {textBox1.SelectionStart + textlength - textBox1.Text.Length - 1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"deleted substring {originalText.Substring(textBox1.SelectionStart, textlength - textBox1.Text.Length)}");
    }
    // reset
    textlength = textBox1.Text.Length;
    originalText = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got so focused in the details of carets and text manipulation that I didn't realize the solution was as simple as formula! (_  _;;)